# how to resolve compiling error -- makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, wxwidgets

I have modified a makefile and trying to compile a project. But it is failing in fist step only.

Even i have specified pattern rule for compiling, w.r.t :--
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage

Makefile is :--

```
# topdir for wxWidgets base 
top_builddir = /opt/wxgtk
EXTRALIBS = -pthread -lz -ldl -lm
LDLIBS = ${APPEXTRALIBS} ${top_builddir}/lib/libwx_baseu-2.8.a ${EXTRALIBS}
CXX         = c++

CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -pthread -I/usr/include/SDL -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy
CPPFLAGS = -D__WXDEBUG__  -I${top_builddir}/wx/include/base-unicode-release-static-2.8  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1
CFLAGS = ${APPEXTRACFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -O2 -MMD -pthread -Wall
CFLAGS  += -DLINUX

CANALOBJS =     ../../common/listenthread_unix.o ../../common/clientthread_level1_unix.o ../../common/devicethread_unix.o \
        ../../common/canalshmem_level1_unix.o ../../common/clientlist.o ../../common/controlobject.o \
        ../../common/devicelist.o ../../common/udpreceivethread_unix.o ../../../vscp/common/vscp.o \
        ../../common/clientthread_level2_unix.o ../../common/canalshmem_level2_unix.o \
        ../../common/tcplistenthread.o
CANALHDRS = ../../common/clientlist.h ../../common/controlobject.h ../../common/devicelist.h \
        ../../common/canal.h ../../common/canaldlldef.h \
        ../../common/version.h ../../common/canal_unix_ipc.h ../../common/CanalShMem_level1_unix.h \
        ../../common/CanalShMem_level2_unix.h ../../common/clientthread_level1_unix.h ../../common/clientthread_level2_unix.h
PROJOBJS    = ../../../common/dllist.o ../../../common/configfile.o ../../../common/crc.o
PROJHDRS    = ../../../common/dllist.h ../../../common/configfile.h
OBJS        = canald.o
HDRS        = canald.h

all:        canald

# Build the Linux executable
canald:     $(OBJS) $(HDRS) $(CANALOBJS) $(CANALHDR) $(PROJOBJS) $(PROJHDRS)
        $(CXX)  -o canald $(OBJS) $(CANALOBJS) $(PROJOBJS) -L$(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJS) $(CANALOBJS) $(PROJOBJS):%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

error i am getting :--

```
make
make: *** No rule to make target `canald.cpp', needed by `canald.o'.  Stop.
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error ?

EDITED :-------

file was missing... its compiling ... but getting following error

```
vscpd.cpp:47:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [vscpd.o] Error 1
```

I have installed wxgtk at following location :---

```
/opt/wxgtk
```

.profile is modified :--

```
PATH = $PATH:/opt/wxgtk
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/wxgtk/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Make is not able to find

```
#include<wx/wx.h>
```

How to resolve it ?

Comment: Is `canald.cpp` available in your current directory?

Comment: thanks .. i have edited my post ... please suggest on it.

Comment: use the -I flag to point at header files in nonstandard locations.

Comment: -I flag should be used for each header file ... or to the folder which contains all header file / ---- like --->>>  -I${top_builddir}/wx/include/

Answer (score 1):

You **must** use `wx-config` instead of specifying the include paths directly, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310972/how-to-use-wxwidget2-9-2-in-linux/8311022#8311022).

Your makefile is pretty strange as you define `CXXFLAGS` only to never use it and instead use `CPPFLAGS` as part of `CFLAGS`. So in your case you need to replace `CPPFLAGS` definition with a `wx-config` invocation, e.g.

```
WX_CONFIG := /opt/wxgtk/bin/wx-config
CPPFLAGS := $(shell $(WX_CONFIG) --cxxflags)
```

Better, get rid of `CPPFLAGS` and define `CXXFLAGS` like this and use it.

Also update your `LDLIBS` to use `wx-config` too:

```
LDLIBS := ${APPEXTRALIBS} $(shell $(WX_CONFIG) --libs)
```

(`EXTRALIBS` shouldn't be normally needed at all any more).